# What difference does it make whether "docker run -ti ubuntu:latest" is passed "bash"?

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am new to the linux world and trying to learn Docker.

I have two examples:

```
#example 1
$ docker run -ti ubuntu:latest bash

#example 2
$ docker run -ti ubuntu:latest
```

In example 1 it would allow me access to the terminal and example 2 is the same outcome. I understand that adding bash creates a bash session, and if that means being able run bash scripts, I am able to do `echo` on both examples, so I do not really see the difference.

What exactly does adding `bash` to `docker run` do? Given this context, what is the difference of having and not having a `bash` argument?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying an explicit command overrides the default command given in the Dockerfile.

**If the default `CMD` in the Dockerfile is already bash, then specifying `bash` on the command line has no effect.**

If you look at [the ubuntu Dockerfile on github](https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile), you can see that that is the case here:

> ```
> CMD ["bash"]
> ```

Thus, you're just explicitly asserting the command *that is already run by default anyhow*.